# Regression evaluation in R

Tags: r

Are there any utilities/packages for showing various performance metrics of a regression model on some labeled test data?  Basic stuff I can easily write like RMSE, R-squared, etc., but maybe with some extra utilities for visualization, or reporting the distribution of prediction confidence/variance, or other things I haven't thought of.  This is usually reported in most training utilities (like caret's train), but only over the training data (AFAICT).  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are wrong about **caret** - section 4 of http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretTrain.pdf shows how to use that package to evaluate test set performance.

Comment: To those considering a close vote - I see a real question here and it is not the one @Chase has Answered; it is more specific than that. I guess it boils down to; "What R package(s) can be used to evaluated a model in a machine learning context?"

Comment: I had read through that PDF and section 4 only shows this for classification, not regression.

Comment: no it doesn't, read the first line. It might only demonstrate *how* to use the function for classification but caret handles regression just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap confidence intervals for parameters of models can be computed using the recommended package **boot**. It is a very general package requiring you to write a simple wrapper function to return the parameter of interest, say fit the model with some supplied data and return one of the model coefficients, whilst it takes care of the rest, doing the sampling and computation of intervals etc.

Consider also the **caret** package, which is a wrapper around a large number of modelling functions, but also provides facilities to compare model performance using a range of metrics using an independent test set or a resampling of the training data (*k*-fold, bootstrap). **caret** is well documented and quite easy to use, though to get the best out of it, you do need to be familiar with the modelling function you want to employ.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about boot. As for my question, could you be more specific w.r.t. caret? It's these facilities for comparing regression model performance on independent test sets that I cannot find, even after searching the reference.

Comment: @Yang The *first* line of section 4 mentions regression: "A function, postResample, can be used obtain the same performance measures as generated by train for regression or classification." So look at the help for that function. My experience is that caret works for regression just like for classification, but with appropriate measurements (like MSE or RMSEP). You're going to have to do a bit of work yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I had read that (and your last document too), but would never have guessed that was what I sought. Seems to only show RMSE and R2, though.

Comment: @Yang I don't think there will be the **one** tool that does everything you want. Confidence intervals on parameters is of lesser importance in machine learning, either because many of the techniques don't really have parameters, or the concern is just on predictive ability. You could use **caret** to do some of the work and then use **boot** to get bootstrap CIs for parameters. As for prediction confidence intervals, *k*-fold CV could give a standard error and the bootstrap could be used to generate prediction intervals. But some of this you are going to have to put together yourself.

Answer (score 6):

This question is really quite broad and should be focused a bit, but here's a *small* subset of functions written to work with linear models:

```
x <- rnorm(seq(1,100,1))
y <- rnorm(seq(1,100,1))
model <- lm(x~y)

#general summary
summary(model)
#Visualize some diagnostics
plot(model)
#Coefficient values
coef(model)
#Confidence intervals
confint(model)
#predict values
predict(model)
#predict new values
predict(model, newdata = data.frame(y = 1:10))
#Residuals
resid(model)
#Standardized residuals
rstandard(model)
#Studentized residuals
rstudent(model)
#AIC
AIC(model)
#BIC
BIC(model)
#Cook's distance
cooks.distance(model)
#DFFITS
dffits(model)
#lots of measures related to model fit
influence.measures(model)
```

Comment: These cover some of what I'm looking for, albeit all over the place.  No MSE, RMSE, MAE, MAPE, RSE, R2, etc.?  Nothing to tie everything together a la caret?

Comment: These are all based on the training data, whereas Yang (and now me too) are looking for methods to evaluate on test data.